# Архитектура базы данных пользователей

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Сейчас у меня есть таблица 'users' с полями типа 
id, email, pass, fname, lastname, city, county,  bday, joindate.. и еще парочку.

Если нужно больше информации о пользователе (еще полей 10-20, может и больше) то добавлять их в эту же таблицу или лучше создать отдельную?

Comment: Храните в одной таблице.

Comment: Зависит от того, могут ли такие поля еще появляться в будущем. Если надо один раз добавить набор полей и все - то в ту же таблицу. Если предполагается, что поля могут время от времени появляться и не хочется каждый раз править программу, то возможно стоит использовать отдельную таблицу где каждое значение отдельной строкой (такой подход называется EAV)